# Spring boot MVN clean package takes more time only in EC2 instance

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, spring-data-jpa

Hi i am having doubt that when i am running maven command in my local machine

```
mvn clean package
```

it took only 37s to complete but same code same command when i am running it in amazon EC2 instanse it taking more than 30 mins still it's not getting complete.

application property file

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=mymail@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class= javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback= flase
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true

        spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://ENDPOINT.OF.AWS.RDS:0000/myblog
spring.datasource.username=name
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false'
```

my confusion is when same code getting build with in 37s but in amazon ec2 instance taking more time. if anything need to change or i am missing. please help to understand.

in this place it taking more time the command is

[image: please see]

Comment: this sounds like a caching issue. Maven downloads dependencies and plugins into a local maven repository. If your EC2 instance does not keep that cache maven will re-do these steps. Just compare the timestamps of the several phases (compile, test, package) to figure out where the time is lost. If its all at the beginning its because of downloading things.

Comment: @wemu it's the first stage compile took only 12s but this taking more time not ending actually. i am stuck with this.

Comment: well something seems to be going on. I would execute the build with "-X" to enable debug log and see what maven is doing when the build takes forever.

Comment: @wemu same place after build with -X also it waiting  in same place..

Comment: well I have no crystal ball. I don't know what your test is doing, it's stuck there where the screenshot is? The Version class contains nothing that would make you wait: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations/blob/master/src/main/java/org/hibernate/annotations/common/Version.java - so I would enable hibernate debug log. It's in the middle of database connection setup / persistence unit creation - maybe the DB is not available yet?